# Woocommerce Salesforce Syntax Error

Tags: error, required

We are using a plugin to connect Salesforce and WooCommerce. When submitting a quote through WooCommerce, we are getting a Syntax JSON error. When debugging, we get the following as the culprit:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#140 (3) {
    ["message"]=>
    string(35) "Required fields are missing: [Name]"
    ["errorCode"]=>
    string(22) "REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING"
    ["fields"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "Name"
    }
  }
}
```

We are pushing First and Last name as required, but "Name" appears to be a fieldset name of sorts. Sorry, newbie here with SF web to lead.

Any help greatly appreciated...plugin author not responding :/

Comment: Which object you are trying to insert in Salesforce ?

Comment: is this the WooCommerce Zapier plugin?

Comment: This is the WooCommerce to Salesforce CRM Integration plugin

Answer (score 0):

The Name field is required on almost all Salesforce records. It's not a particularly important field (other than you generally have to have it) - you can fill it with what you like - Perhaps a combination of FirstName and LastName or some other concatenated data.

Try doing that and see how you go.

What you can do also is set the Name field later via a workflow with something meaningful - but for now, the important thing is that there is some non-null string in it.

Comment: Thanks for the tips - but we are submitting first and last names. So I am not sure why we are getting the [Name] missing field error?

Comment: You can't create a record in Salesforce without the Name field - so although you are submitting First and Last names, you will need to also submit something in the Name field.